# Query optimization when no row is returned

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, explain, query-performance

I am using explain to figure out what is happening in my query which is:

```
explain select t from c where u1_id = 1 group by t;
```

I see "*Using where*" in the Extra column of the resultset. But this only happens if I use a valid u1_id. So if I run the same query, on the same server but with an invalid u1_id I get "*Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort*" in the Extra column.

I assume this means that when the user_id is not in the table then MySQL takes another route to process the query. Does anyone know why this happens and how can I prevent this from happening?

**EDIT**

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE  c  (
   pk  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   u1_id  int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   u2_id  int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   s  decimal(11,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0.00000'',
   date  datetime NOT NULL,
   f  decimal(11,5) NOT NULL,
   t  enum(''F'',''P'') ,
   ti  decimal(11,5) DEFAULT ''0.00000'',
   ts  decimal(11,5) DEFAULT ''0.00000'',
   latest  tinyint(1) DEFAULT ''0'',
   sc  decimal(11,5) DEFAULT ''0.00000'',
   p_id  int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ( pk ),
  KEY  i1  ( u1_id ),
  KEY  i2  ( u2_id ),
  KEY  i3  ( u1_id , u2_id ),
  KEY  i4  ( sc ),
  KEY  i5  ( sc , u2_id , latest ),
  KEY  i5  ( p_id ),
  KEY  i8  ( ti ),
  KEY  i9  ( t ),
  KEY  i10  ( p_id , u1_id , latest , t ),
 )
```

Comment: Please display the full output of `explain select type from c where user_id = 1 group by type;` as is.

Comment: Is `user_id` the primary key? Is it an indexed field?

Comment: Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE c\G` so we can see the indexes.

Comment: I guess you have an index on `type` but not any index on `user_id` or on `(user_id, type)`?

Comment: Your table `c` does not have a column called `user_id` or a column called `type`.  Please update your question with a table definition and a query that match each other.

Comment: Add the explain plans so we knwo which indexes are being used. But anyway, an index on `(u1_id, t)` would be the best for this query and would eliminate any "using temporary; using filesort", in either case.

Comment: @ypercube your comment about `index on (u1_id,t)` should be an answer. +1 on the comment. The index would prevent reaching into the table for needed data, which in this case is a very good thing given the query.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA thnx

Answer (score 2):

The best index for this query is `(u1_id, t)`

My initial guess was right, that you have indexes on `(t)` alone and on `(u1_id)` alone. You haven't told us the exact `EXPLAIN` output (which index is used), so the most probable explanation is that mysql is choosing to use one of these existing indexes or none at all (doing a full scan of the table), which yields the not so efficient plan.